# Sklearn Transformers: How to apply encoder to multiple columns and reuse it in production?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using label encoder during training and want to use same encoder in production by saving it and loading it later. Whatever solutions I have found online only allow Label Encoder to apply on the single column at a time like below:

```
for col in col_list:
    df[col]= df[[col]].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

In this case how do I save it and use it later? Because I tried fitting on entire datafreame but I am getting following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\DA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3884/730613134.py in <module>
----> 1 l_enc.fit_transform(df_join[le_col].astype(str))

~\anaconda3\envs\ReturnRate\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    113             Encoded labels.
    114         """
--> 115         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    116         self.classes_, y = _unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    117         return y

~\anaconda3\envs\ReturnRate\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
   1022         return np.ravel(y)
   1023 
-> 1024     raise ValueError(
   1025         "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)
   1026     )

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3949037, 14) instead.
```

I want to fit label encoder to dataframe with 10 columns (all categorical), save it and load it later in production.

Comment: are you trying to encode your categorical predictors? If so you should use onehot encoding rather than label encoder. Label encoder is meant for your target variable

Comment: I am using tree classifier, which does not need one hot encoding, also categories are really large in number, hence the label encoding. I know label encoder could be used for each column and saved separately but wanted to know if there is any easier approach?

Answer (score 3):

First, I want to point out [labelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is meant for encoding target variables. If you apply labelEncoder on your predictor variables, you are making them continuous, for example 0,1,2,3 etc, which may not make sense.

For categorical predictors you should use [onehotencoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

If you are sure about labelencode, it goes like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'f1':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'],100),
'f2':np.random.choice(['x','y','z'],100)})

col_list = ['f1','f2']

df[col_list].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

If you want to retain the encoder, you can store it in a dictionary:

```
le = {}
for col in col_list:
    le[col] = LabelEncoder().fit(df[col].values)

le['f1'].transform(df['f1'])

array([1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2,
       2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2,
       0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2,
       0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2])

for col in col_list:
    df[col] = le[col].transform(df[col])
```

Again I would give more thought about whether it is correct to use labelEncoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As per your comment, that label encoder is meant for target variable, how do you encode categories (for independent variable) into numbers when categories present are in thousands (also I read tree classifiers perform worse on OHE compared to LE)? I mean, I am thinking, to convert these text categories in numbers, label encoding was good option, please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: the LE only works when your categories are ordinal, meaning they have some kind of ranking that makes sense. If not you can only do OHE, or you reduce the number of categories by combining them

Comment: I tried this solution and saved the `le` to pickle file. After loading this pickle file, and fitting on the same data I get following error: `ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 0`. It is the same data to get this error. Is it some how possible that encoder that is getting appended to the dictionary is empty?

Comment: you wrote over the original df. can you keep a copy of the dataframe with the original categories

Answer (score 2):

As [@StupidWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69987081/4574633) said, `LabelEncoder` should be used solely to encode target variable.

scikit-learn offers multiple ways to encode categorical variable for feature vector:

- `OneHotEncoder` which encode categories into one hot numeric values
- `OrdinalEncoder` which encode categories into numerical values.

`OrdinalEncoder` performs the same operation as `LabelEncoder` but for feature values.

You can use `ColumnTransformer` to wrapped different preprocessing into one object that can later easily be saved using pickle as in the example below:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer, make_column_selector
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_1": ["A", "B", "B", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B"],
        "col_2": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "X"],
        "col_3": [42] * 8,
    }
)
cols = ["col_1", "col_2"]

pre_processeing = make_column_transformer(
    (OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown="use_encoded_value", unknown_value=np.nan), cols)
)


df.loc[:, cols] = pre_processeing.fit_transform(df[cols])
```

Which output:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    0.0    0.0     42
1    1.0    0.0     42
2    1.0    0.0     42
3    2.0    1.0     42
4    3.0    1.0     42
5    4.0    2.0     42
6    0.0    2.0     42
7    1.0    0.0     42
```

Once the preprocessing is fitted it can easily be stored and loaded using `pickle` as follows:

```
import pickle

#Dump preprocessing
pickle.dump(pre_processeing, open("pre_processing.p", "wb"))

#Load preprocessing
pre_processeing = pickle.load(open("pre_processing.p", "rb"))
```

To conclude, I would advocate that `ColumnTransformer` has the following benefits:

- Additional preprocessing for different columns can easily be added (e.g `StandardScaler` for numerical values)
- This preprocessing can be included within a `Pipeline` to have an end-to-end model that perform prediction
- This is a single object that can be easily serialized with `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

---

> **TL;DR** Use `SklearnTransformerWrapper` from feature-engine library

```
from feature_engine.wrappers import SklearnTransformerWrapper

multi_col_transformer = SklearnTransformerWrapper(
    transformer=# your sklearn- transformer,
    variables=# variables to apply transformation to
)
```

---

If you're looking for an approach with a different library feature-engine [categorical encoders](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.x/#categorical-variable-encoders-encoders) accept a `variables` parameter to apply computation to multiple columns. Another approach is to use `SklearnTransformerWrapper` to apply any Scikit-learn transformers to a group of variables.

```
from feature_engine.wrappers import SklearnTransformerWrapper
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

import pandas as pd
import joblib

transformer_name = 'multi_col_encoder.joblib'
cols_list = [
    'country',
    'category'
]

d_train = {
    'country': ['AR', 'AR', 'MEX', 'BR', 'MEX'],
    'category': ['Small', 'High', 'High', 'Medium', 'Small']
}

d_unknown = {
    'country': ['BR', 'AR', 'MEX'],
    'category': ['High', 'Medium', 'Small']
}

df_train = pd.DataFrame(d_train)
df_unknown = pd.DataFrame(d_unknown)

# Apply a sklearn enconder to multiple columns with SklearnTransformerWrapper
multi_col_oe = SklearnTransformerWrapper(
    transformer=OrdinalEncoder(
        handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-1
    ),
    variables=cols_list
)

df_train = multi_col_oe.fit_transform(df_train)

df_train
>>>
country category
0   0.0 2.0
1   0.0 0.0
2   2.0 0.0
3   1.0 1.0
4   2.0 2.0

# Dump transformer to use later
joblib.dump(multi_col_oe, transformer_name)

# Load transformer with learned encoder logic
transformer_for_prod = joblib.load(transformer_name)

# Apply transformer to unknown data
transformer_for_prod.transform(df_unknown)
>>>
country category
0   1.0 0.0
1   0.0 1.0
2   2.0 2.0
```

As @StupidWolf said, if you're assuming order in your categorical variables you should use `OrdinalEncoder` instead of `LabelEncoder`. Though they perform similar computations, `OrdinalEncoder` allows you to handle unknown values you might encounter later.

Finally, Feature Engine [Categorical Encoders](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.x/#categorical-variable-encoders-encoders) also offer other possibilities to encode categorical variables.

Comment: Shoudn't you have one encoder per column? even if it's repeated. (ingenuous question)